# tripwire report - inode number

Tags: fedora, security, inode

Hi I am investigating tripwire and have stumbled upon something which i am unsure about. in a tripwire report generated after i modified hosts.deny to include an extra # I noticed the inode number changed from 6969 to 6915. I would like to know why this happened. I know inodes are records which store data about where data is stored on the file system, but would like to know why this number changed for a simple # being inserted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard behavior for text editors is to rename the original file to a temporary name before writing out changes, so if there is a problem (such as out of disk space) you don't lose the file entirely.  Thus the file gets a new inode number.  If the editor is configured to leave the original as a backup file, you'll find the backup file has the original inode number; if not, then the backup will have been deleted after the new file was successfully written.

Comment: is there somewhere where I can reference this information. it makes sense but i am not allowed to reference a place such as stackexchange thank you very much :D

Comment: Not offhand; it's a programming best practice, I would expect it to be covered in any book which discusses developing applications.

Comment: @Mintuz: Depending on the circumstances, when you save editor might either create a new file and rename it into place, or write to the original file. There are up- and downsides to both methods. I know this has been discussed before, either on this site or on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/), though I can't find the thread right now.